# Numpy некорректно выводит массив на печать `print(np_array)` (не все элементы). Как вывести все элементы?

Tags: python, numpy

Мне нужно создать массив из большого количества элементов, все работает нормально, когда количество элементов <= 1000. Если элементов больше, то он выводится в таком виде:

```
[32.78088929 67.80323438 14.94252882 ...  5.25943371 22.08549083 12.54776541]
```

Вот код:

```
arr = np.random.triangular(start,mode,end,amount)
print(arr)
with open("data/array.txt","w", newline='') as out:
      print(arr,file=out,sep=" ")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy "уберегает" вас от вывода огромных массивов **на печать**. [По умолчанию на печать выводится 1000 элементов - 500 первых и 500 последних.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html)

При сохранении в файлы (для этого надо использовать методы Numpy: [np.save()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html), [np.savetxt()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html), [np.savez()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html), [np.savez_compressed()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html)) будут сохранены **все** элементы.

При желании максимальное число элементов выводимых на печать можно настроить:

```
In [67]: np.set_printoptions(threshold=10000)
    ...: print(np.arange(2000))
```